# Customizing Liferay 6 Dockbar in Velocity / JS / CSS

Tags: jboss, navigation, liferay, velocity, liferay-6

I'm not a fan of the whole 'portal dockbar' for normal users (we use Liferay for external facing hosting). And I don't want to show people things like 'Go To' etc (I've hidden the private / public pages using things like must be power user to show, etc).

But I want to eliminate things like un-needed icons on the Dockbar for non admin users (see image)
- remove 'Manage' section 
- remove toggle edit controls (shouldn't even be shown to non admin!?)

I think these things cause confusion for logged in 'basic' users.
[image: Liferay Dockbar example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dockbar is a regular portlet, you can modify it as such. It just differs in display because there's some fancy css included in the standard theme, but otherwise there's nothing different customizing the dockbar portlet than for any other portlet.

So you just need to create a hook and override the JSP(s) you'd like -> done.

Answer (score 5):

Keep the following entry in portal_normal.vm file of your theme

```
#if($is_signed_in)
#if($permissionChecker.isCompanyAdmin($company_id))
#dockbar()
#end
```

With this code Dockbar will be visible to only Admin.